# C++11: Difference between Test* test = new Test; and Test* test = new Test();

Tags: c++11, constructor, initialization, new-operator

Under C++11, if 'Test' is an ordinary class, is there any difference between:

```
Test* test = new Test;
//and
Test* test = new Test();
```

Note: this is the same question [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) asked again, because the old thread is before C++11, while I'd like to ask if there's a difference under c++11 stadard.

The accepted answer of that question says:

- In C++1998 there are 2 types of initialization: zero and default In
- C++2003 a 3rd type of initialization, value initialization was added.

I understand that C++11 only has 2 initialization, default and value. So i fancy the answer are a bit different?

Comment: have you looked at this? >> [pods](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#PODs)

Comment: What do you mean by "ordinary class"? Are there extraordinary ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 has zero-initialization, default-initialization, value-initialization (**8.5/5**, **/6** and **/7**, correspondingly), copy-initialization (**8.5/14**), direct-initialization (**8.5/15**) and list-initialization (**8.5.4**).

With respect to `new` in particular:

> **5.3.4/15** A *new-expression* that creates an object of type `T` initializes that object as follows:
>
> — If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5); if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.
>
> — Otherwise, the *new-initializer* is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know there's "zero-initialization" in C++11 -- as far as I could remember "C++ Primer" seems only introduced default and value initialization. May I ask what is "8.5/5"? Where could I check the detailed content?